# Get value to .ejs with .js function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

What am I doing wrong?

I've two mongodb data tables. With a value of the first table, i'd like to search in the second en get a value back.

So in my .ejs:

```
<%= getdes(Object.Filename) %>
```

In my .js

```
function getdes(fName) {
    let xyz = getdes2(fName).then((value) => { // This must be the trick to rip value from promise?
        console.log('Test ' + value) //Works! Gives value when found.
        return value; //Huh? No value written back to ejs?
    });
    return xyz // Gives [object Promise] in .ejs
}
async function getdes2(fName) {
    try {
        const file = await File.findOne({ filename: fName }, File._id)
        return await file.title
    } catch {
        return 'Not found'
    }
}
```

Who can help me to get my value in my .ejs file?

Comment: Aren't you missing a return in getdes? Try adding `return xyz;` in your `getdes` function.

Comment: See edit. That returns [object Promise]. I googled a lot, everyone has problems with getting values out of promises. Still no solution found.